# How to insert multiple appended/nested array elements in DB using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a page with some fields that the user can fill. In the main selector the user can only select some predefined options, in the custom selector the user can fill other fields, with more detailed options. There is a button that append one more layer, with all these options again, and a save button that will save all the things that was filled. Something like this:

```
Main Selector
|_Selector

Custom Selector
|_Name
|_Type
|_Attribute
|_numOfOptions (When selected, opens a number of fields related to number)
  |_value
  |_color

(New Layer button)
(Save Button)
```

Now they all have the same name and save the data as an array (ex: `<input name="color[]">`). When I save the data in the page, after append some elements, I get the all the data the same time and mixed.

I know WHY this is happening, and I imagine one way to solve this, but I'm not sure if is the correct way. I think I can get the total elements in one layer from JavaScript and pass this number to PHP, then I can iterate the value only this number of times. In the next loop I can start where the previous loop stopped.

**Extreme simplified PHP code, without any query:**

```
$nomeCamada = $_POST['nomeCamada'];
$attrName = $_POST['attrName'];
$tipoSelector = $_POST['tipoSelector'];
foreach($nomeCamada as $value2) {
    $key = array_search($value2, $nomeCamada);
    echo "Saving in DB...  CustomSelector: " . $value2 . " | Attr name: " . $attrName[$key] . " | Type: " . $tipoSelector[$key] . "<br>";
    $attrValue = $_POST['attrValue'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    foreach ($attrValue as $value3) {
        $key2 = array_search($value3, $attrValue);
        echo "____Class name " . $value2 . " | Attr name: " . $attrName[$key] . " | Attr value: " . $value3 . " | Attr color: " . $color[$key2] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**Output (Showing 1 main element and 2 custom, the first with 2 attributes and the last with 3. The scratched elements are those who are saving incorrectly.):**

```
Saving in DB... Selector: Main
Saving in DB... CustomSelector: CustomLayer1 | Attribute: attr1 | Type: type1
____Class name: CustomLayer1 | Attr name: attr1 | Attr value: 2 | Attr color: #ff0000
____Class name: CustomLayer1 | Attr name: attr1 | Attr value: 4 | Attr color: #000000
____Class name: CustomLayer1 | Attr name: attr1 | Attr value: 10 | Attr color: #ffff00
____Class name: CustomLayer1 | Attr name: attr1 | Attr value: 20 | Attr color: #800040
____Class name: CustomLayer1 | Attr name: attr1 | Attr value: 30 | Attr color: #8000ff
Saving in DB... CustomSelector: CustomLayer2 | Attribute: attr2 | Type: type2
____Class name: CustomLayer2 | Attr name: attr2 | Attr value: 2 | Attr color: #ff0000
____Class name: CustomLayer2 | Attr name: attr2 | Attr value: 4 | Attr color: #000000
____Class name: CustomLayer2 | Attr name: attr2 | Attr value: 10 | Attr color: #ffff00
____Class name: CustomLayer2 | Attr name: attr2 | Attr value: 20 | Attr color: #800040
____Class name: CustomLayer2 | Attr name: attr2 | Attr value: 30 | Attr color: #8000ff
```

As I say, I don't know if this is the ideal way to do this. I'm also can fix this saving one layer at a time, but I really want so save all the same time. Let me know if this post needs any edition.

Comment: Please don't use tags that are not related to your question.

Comment: Wich one do you mean?

Comment: `jquery`, `html`, `javascript` - I believe.

Comment: Can you not wrap in in an array and store it all as JSON?

Comment: Well, as I say in the post, maybe one possible solution is to get the index from the JS/Jquery function, so I think is related. Removed the HTML though. I didn't think about that JSON approach yet, going to study if is worth it, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by the JS approach I mentioned earlier. I got the number of attributes generated by the user as a JS var and passed to the PHP file as a `hidden input`, inside de main form. In the PHP file I iterated using this value as range. In the next iteration I got the last value of the previous iteration to define the new starting range.

```
if (isset($lastValue)) {
        foreach (range($lastValue+1, $lastValue+$classNumber[$x]) as $indexValue) {
            $key2 = array_search($indexValue, $attrValue);
            echo "____Nome da Classe " . $value2 . " | Nome do atributo: " . $attrName[$key] . " | Valor do Atributo: " . $attrValue[$indexValue] . " | Cor do Atributo: " . $color[$indexValue] . "<br>";              
        }
        $lastValue = $lastValue+$classNumber[$x];

} else {
        foreach (range(0, $classNumber[$x]-1) as $indexValue) {
            $key2 = array_search($indexValue, $attrValue);
            echo "____Nome da Classe " . $value2 . " | Nome do atributo: " . $attrName[$key] . " | Valor do Atributo: " . $attrValue[$indexValue] . " | Cor do Atributo: " . $color[$indexValue] . "<br>";
        }
        $lastValue = $classNumber[$x]-1;
}

$x++;
```